# How do i get the expanded jqGrid row column data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

When Main jqGrid row is expanded a subgrid is constructed and displayed. I need to capture main grid expanded row column data before subgrid is constructed. For that i'm using  subGridBeforeExpand event of Main Grid. In that event the i'm calling a javascript code to capture expanded row column data but with out any success . **alert throws sel_id as null**. Could any one guide me on this?. Do i need to use another grid event or something wrong with my jquery code?.

```
**<script type="text/javascript">
     function GetValues() {
       var sel_id = jQuery("#ServersWS").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); 
       alert(sel_id);
       var rowData = jQuery("#ServersWS").jqGrid('getRowData', sel_id);
       var temp = rowData['Description']; //replace name with you column
       alert(temp);
    }
</script>**     

 div id="gridWrapper1" style="display: none">
    @{

        var grid1 = new JqGridHelper<Configuration.Models.Post.ProfileModel>(
            "ServersWS",
            caption: "Server Profiles With One or More Settings",
            hidden: false,
            hiddenEnabled: true,
            dataType: JqGridDataTypes.Json,
            methodType: JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
            pager: true,
            rowsNumber: 10,
            sortingName: "Profile",
            sortingOrder: JqGridSortingOrders.Asc,
            url: Url.Action("GetServersWithSettings"),
            **subGridBeforeExpand: "function(id) {GetValues();}",**
            subgridEnabled: true,
            subgridHelper: new JqGridHelper<PlatformConfigurationEditModel>(
                "ProfileSettingsEdit",
                caption: "Edit Settings",
                hidden: false,
                hiddenEnabled: true,
                dataType: JqGridDataTypes.Json,
                methodType: JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
                pager: true,
                rowsNumber: 10,
                sortingName: "Id",
                sortingOrder: JqGridSortingOrders.Asc,
                url: Url.Action("GetEditableProfileSettings"),
                editingUrl: Url.Action("Edit"),
                viewRecords: true,
                autoWidth: true,
                sortable: true)
                .Navigator(new JqGridNavigatorOptions { Search = false },
                    new JqGridNavigatorEditActionOptions { Url = Url.Action
                    ("Update"),CloseAfterAdd = true, CloseAfterEdit = true, Width = 500, Height  
                     = 300 },
                    new JqGridNavigatorEditActionOptions { Url = Url.Action("Add"), 
                    CloseAfterAdd = true, CloseAfterEdit = true, Width = 500, Height = 300 },
                    new JqGridNavigatorDeleteActionOptions { Url = Url.Action("Delete") },
                    null, new JqGridNavigatorViewActionOptions { LabelsWidth = "60%" }
                )
                .FilterToolbar(options: new JqGridFilterToolbarOptions
                {
                    StringResult = true,
                    DefaultSearchOperator = JqGridSearchOperators.Cn,
                    AutoSearch = true,
                    SearchOnEnter = false
                }),
                sortable: true
            ).FilterToolbar(new JqGridFilterToolbarOptions
            {
                StringResult = true,
                DefaultSearchOperator = JqGridSearchOperators.Cn,
                AutoSearch = true,
                SearchOnEnter = false,

            });
        @grid1.GetHtml()
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Oleg would you able to look into this?..@Oleg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with [Lib.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc) library, but you can try to use [jQuery events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2) instead of [callbacks](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events). For example `jqGridSubGridBeforeExpand` could be what you need:

```js
jQuery("#ServersWS").bind("jqGridSubGridBeforeExpand", function (e, pID, rowid) {
    alert("rowid=" + rowid);
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response- How can i get expanded row column data with rowid? @Oleg

Comment: Trying this worked - jQuery("#ServersWS").bind("jqGridSubGridBeforeExpand", function (e, pID, rowid) {
                var rowData = jQuery("#ServersWS").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
                var temp = rowData['Description']; //replace name with you column
                alert(temp);

            });

Comment: Hi @Oleg this is the first step to resolve another issue. How do i modify subgrid navig properties?.Specifically i need to modify edit,add, delete url's -                  Somethings like this  jQuery("#ProfileSettingsEdit").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', {}, { url: url }, { url: 
         url }, {}, {}, {});

Comment: @user845405: You are welcome! I am not understand you last question, because one create typically grid as sub grid and it's navigator bar **directly** inside of `subGridBeforeExpand` callback. Probably it's specific Lib.Web.Mvc question?